# Como passar variáveis como parâmetro num objeto JSON no Swift?

Tags: json, swift, post

Estou fazendo uma chamada `POST` com Swift usando a biblioteca Alamofire. A chamada de serviço funciona, mas eu preciso verificar o **email** e a **senha** digitada pelo usuário.

Como é que faço para passar as variáveis `email` e `senha` no `parameters` do JSON?
Desde já agradeço. Segue a parte do meu código que estou precisando de ajuda:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["title": "Frist Psot", "body": "I iz fisrt", "userId": 1]

do {
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
} catch{

}

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.response) // URL response
print(response.result)

if let JSON = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(JSON)")

    let usuario = JSON.objectForKey("data");
    print(usuario)
    //String nome = JSON.objectForKey("nome") == nil ? "" :JSON.objectForKey("nome") as! String;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito obrigada pela ajuda. Eu consegui acessar o meu json como objeto assim:

if let JSON = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: (JSON)")

```
let idUsuario = dataJSON["id"]
let nomeUsuario = dataJSON["nome"]
print(usuario)
```

}

Dessa forma ele identifica os parâmetros "id" e "nome" e busca seus valores. Muito obrigada, Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user a sintaxe "if let" igual você fez mais a cima, em conjunto do "as?" :

```
  if let nome = jsonResult.objectForKey("nome") as? String {
            print(nome)
        }
```

Outra forma é usar o "as?" e verificar posteriormente:

```
var nome = jsonResult.objectForKey("nome") as? String
var senha = jsonResult.objectForKey("senha") as? String

if(nome != nil && senha != nil){
   print("\(nome) - \(senha)")
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada :)